# Dereference iterator as part of a boost::bind composite chain

Tags: c++, boost, bind, composite, dereference

I am trying to use bind to produce a function that:

- Receives a map m
- returns m.begin()->first

For that I am trying to use boost::bind:

```
typedef map<int,int>::const_iterator (map<int,int>::*const_begin_end) () const;
bind(&pair<const int,int>::first, bind(static_cast<const_begin_end>(&map<int, int>::begin), _1));
```

This doesn't work because the result of begin needs to be dereferenced. I thought something like

```
bind(&pair<const int,int>::first, bind(&operator*, bind(static_cast<const_begin_end>(&map<int, int>::begin), _1)));
```

But this wouldn't work since there is no global operator*.

Questions:

- Is it possible to achieve this using boost::bind composite chains? How?
- More easily readable alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html), it's my go-to library when it comes to writing functors on the fly in C++03. It is a superior alternative to Boost.Bind -- that library is showing its age.

For instance, Phoenix let us use operators on its functors to represent an actual use of that operator when the functor is called. Thus `arg1 + arg2` is a functor that returns the sum of its first two operands. This heavily cuts down on the `bind` noise. A first attempt could look like:

```
bind(&pair<const int, int>::first
     , *bind(static_cast<const_begin_end>(&map<int, int>::begin), arg1)) )
```

([LWS demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/37qYCp%248))

But another strong point of Phoenix is that it comes with some batteries. In our case we're very much interested in `<boost/phoenix/stl/container.hpp>` because this includes some lazy version of the familiar containers operations, including `begin`. This is very handy in our case:

```
// We don't need to disambiguate which begin member we want anymore!
bind(&pair<const int, int>::first, *begin(arg1))
```

([LWS demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/37qYCp%247))

---

As a final note, I'll add that C++11 bind expressions are specified such that pointer-to-members work on *anything* that uses `operator*`. So out-of-the-box you can do:

```
bind(&pair<const int, int>::first, bind(static_cast<begin_type>(&std::map<int, int>::begin), _1))
```

([LWS demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Kg46J%247))

Answer (score 1):

you can call bind with member function pointers, and member operators are nothing else but member functions:

```
 const_begin_end pBegin = &map<int,int>::begin;
 x = bind(&std::pair::first, 
    bind(&std::map<int, int>::const_iterator::operator*, 
      bind(pBegin, _1)
    );
```

But seriously, you can as well just write a proper function that does what you need instead of that unreadable boost.bind mess (can you say "maintainability"?).

So, for C++03, a function:

```
template <class Map>
typename Map::key_type keyBegin(Map const& m)
{ 
  return m.begin().first;
}
```

or a C++03 functor (you can define it locally inside your function)

```
struct KeyBegin
{
  typedef std::map<int, int> IntMap;
  int operator()(IntMap const& m) {
    return m.begin().first;
  }
};
```

or a C++11 lambda (more readable than a bind orgy):

```
auto keyBegin = [](std::map<int, int> const& m) -> int {
  return std::begin(m).first;
};
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, but I wanted something that worked not only for map::const_iterator but for any iterator (including pointers). The map thing was only an example.